# Get compilation date as output

Tags: .net, matlab, version-control, compilation

I have a matlab program that is called in .NET to do some calculations and generate output.

I would like to have some kind of automatic version detection.

For example, when the program is run, I would like the compilation(build) date to be written to the database next to the outputs. (I don't care what happens when I run the uncompiled code)

I know how to do this manually by changing the source code every time I build, but I am looking for a way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you know that MatLab is interpreted language, so there is no compilation date.

As a workaround you may do this. In your program add these lines:

```
try
    CompilationDateTime = GetCompilationDateTime
catch
    % GetCompilationDateTime not found
    CompilationDateTime = 0   % the default compilation date/time
end
```

Then use this function

```
function UpdateCompilationDateInCurrentDir
    fh = fopen('GetCompilationDateTime.m','w');
    fprintf(fh, 'function res = GetCompilationDateTime\n');
    fprintf(fh, 'res = %s\n',num2str(now));
    fprintf(fh, 'end\n');
    fclose(fh);
end
```

So you have to call `UpdateCompilationDateInCurrentDir` right before you compile your application (manually or from a build script) and the current date/tile will be imprinted into `GetCompilationDateTime` function for later use.

Comment: I think @DennisJaheruddin is compiling his code, with MATLAB Builder for .NET.

Comment: Never tried the MATLAB builder for .NET, `pcode` was enough so far.
In any case this problem is broader and does not depend on the way one converts *.m files into binary form.
The point is that regardless the way you prefer to compile/deploy/pcode your MATLAB code, you need to store the build timestamp somewhere in source.
In this case it will be integrated into your app by your builder/compiler tool.
Now one has to find the most comfortable way to update the timestamp.
In this sense MATLAB-only solution is preferrable because MATLAB is always present when *.m coed is compiled.

Comment: Very nice thinking. I have now succeeded in creating a function based on yours. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @anandr I eventually came up with a little function. It does exactly what he suggested plus a little extra. It should not be hard to generalize this.

```
function usedeploytooltobuildfoo
% Update the m file that contains the date and build foo
%% Specifics of this project
my_function_name = 'foo';
location_of_project = 'C:\fooproject.prj';
%% General
% Find the location of the function, this is where we will write the new timestamp function
location_of_mainfunction = which(my_function_name); 
location_of_mainfunction = location_of_mainfunction(1:end-2-length(my_function_name)); %Truncate the end of the path
% Design the function that can be used to read out the timestamp
my_new_functionstring = ['function t = myTimeStamp; t=' datestr(now,'YYYYmmDDHHMM') ';'];
% Write the new timestamp function
fid = fopen([location_of_mainfunction 'myTimeStamp.m'],'w');
fprintf(fid,'%s',my_new_functionstring); 
fclose(fid);
% Now execute the build
deploytool('-build',location_of_project)
```

Now in the code I can just call `myTimeStamp` and write it as output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using source control? If so, then you should be able to get it to automatically insert the revision number (and/or the current date and time) into your source somewhere during a checkout.

If you insert it in a place (such as within the output of a `sprintf` statement), then your code should be able to report its revision number.

Lastly, only build from just-checked-out code.

Comment: I use Code-Coop for source control. This is pretty much just point and click, so I don't access is programmatically. Therefore I think this may not be the right direction for me.

Comment: I use Subversion with TortoiseSVN, which is also completely point and click. I don't know about Code-Coop directly, but in my system you can add keywords (typically within comments) to your source files - Tortoise will then auto-replace the keyword with the date, revision, author etc when you do a point-and-click checkout. Although the keywords are typically within comments, they don't have to be, and could be within the content of a `sprintf` statement.